# Laravel where condition - pgsql query

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, laravel-8, rest

I want to select the value in `MaxFileSize` column ,for which the `FileType` column in the same table has a value equal to `$fileType`. That is, in this example, if the uploadType i'm inputting is mp4 , i need to get the result (that is, $maxSize ) as 6.

```
$fileType=$request->uploadType;
$maxSize = Filesizes::where('FileType',$fileType)->get(['MaxFileSize']);
```

I have tried the above code and am not able to get my desired result with this code. Pls help me with ur suggestions.

**filesizes Table**

| MaxFileSize | FileType |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | mp4 |

The above code gives an output as this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1313
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => App\Models\Filesizes {#1314
      #table: "filesizes"
      #fillable: array:1 [
        0 => "MaxFileSize"
      ]
      #connection: "pgsql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:1 [
        "MaxFileSize" => 6
      ]
      #original: array:1 [
        "MaxFileSize" => 6
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: array:1 [
        "deleted_at" => "datetime"
      ]
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [
        0 => "*"
      ]
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: whats the error and what you want achieve .so that some one can help you

Comment: @JohnLobo please see the updated question. I have added the output i'm getting in it. For the example i have given, if the `uploadType` i'm inputting  is mp4 , i need to get the result (that is, `$maxSize` ) as 6.

Comment: $maxSize = Filesizes::where('FileType',$fileType)->get(['MaxFileSize','FileType']);

Comment: if you want to readable format then dd($maxSize->toArray());

Comment: @JohnLobo I have tried this - `dd($maxSize->toArray());` . But it shows an output like this -  `array:1 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "MaxFileSize" => 6
  ]
]` .However, what i need as output is just 6.

Comment: then check @n69s answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value directly from one query use the method `value()`

```
$maxSize = Filesizes::where('FileType',$fileType)->value('MaxFileSize');
```