# Laravel Where Clause - Pgsql query

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, laravel-8, rest

I want to know whether any value of the column `fileType` has the value of `$fileType`. I want to give an error msg if there is no atleast 1 such row. I'm getting a wrong but big output for `dd($data);` here. May i know how to accomplish this correctly

```
    $data=Filesizes::where('FileType',$fileType);
    dd($data);
    die();
    if($data){
      Uploads::create($dataToInsert);
   }
   else{
      return response()->json(['status'=>'Failed']);
   }
```

Comment: Use the same variable you got from `value()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68297144/laravel-where-condition-pgsql-query Wait, is this a test given by your teacher ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have use first or exists

```
$data=Filesizes::where('FileType',$fileType)->exists();

    if($data){
      Uploads::create($dataToInsert);
   }
   else{
      return response()->json(['status'=>'Failed']);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `->get()`, `->first()` or `->exists()` to actually retrieve your results, at the moment `$data` is a Query Builder object and not a collection of `Filesizes`.

I'd recommend `Filesizes` being singular too, i.e. `Filesize`, as that tends to be the convention for model names, same for `Uploads`.

```
$data = Filesizes::where('FileType', $fileType)->get();

if ($data->count() > 0) {
    Uploads::create($dataToInsert);
} else {
    return response()->json(['status'=>'Failed']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `first()` of `count()` to check record exist or not:

```
$data=Filesizes::where('FileType',$fileType)->first();

if($data){
  Uploads::create($dataToInsert);
}
else{
  return response()->json(['status'=>'Failed']);
}
```

By `count()`

```
$data=Filesizes::where('FileType',$fileType)->count();

if($data > 0){
  Uploads::create($dataToInsert);
}
else{
  return response()->json(['status'=>'Failed']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ca use the result you already have, you dont need to do a second seperate query to get the maxFileSize

```
$maxFileSize = Filesizes::where('FileType',$fileType)->value('MaxFileSize');

if($maxFileSize !== null){
    Uploads::create($dataToInsert);
} else {
    return response()->json(['status'=>'Failed'], 422);
}
```